# Real part of electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, complex-numbers

If I want to calculate $(\Re(\vec{E}))^2$ of $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t)}$ how get I $|\vec{E}_0|^2\cos^2(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t)$?
I would say that $\Re(\vec{E}_0\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t)})={\Re(\vec{E}_0)\cos(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t)})-\Im(\vec{E}_0)\sin(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t))$ but the solution says only $\Re(\vec{E}_0) \cos(\vec{k}\vec{x}-\omega t)$.

Comment: $\Re(e^{ix}) = \cos(x)$ so $(\Re(e^{ix}))^2 = \cos^2(x)$. I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @JohnRennie yes but for the product not.

Comment: Do you mean $\Re(\mathbf E^2)$ rather than $(\Re(\mathbf E))^2$

Comment: @JohnRennie no but $\vec{E}_0$ is complex too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field is real. When people write
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{E}_0 e^{i( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t) },
\end{equation}
they imply that the physical electric field is the real part of this expression, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_{\textrm{phys}} = \textrm{Re}(\mathbf{E})  = \mathbf{E}_0 \cos( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t). 
\end{equation}
Your second expression is the intensity, which is the square of the electric field,
\begin{equation}
I = \mathbf{E}_{\textrm{phys}}^2 = \mathbf{E}^2_0 \cos^2( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t). 
\end{equation}

This assumes that $\mathbf{E}_0$ is real. If it is not, there are two possibilities:

(a) $\mathbf{E}_0 = e^{i\phi} \mathbf{E}'_0$ with real $\mathbf{E}'_0$. Then the physical electric field is simply phase shifted,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_{\textrm{phys}} = \textrm{Re}(\mathbf{E})  = \mathbf{E}_0 \cos( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t + \phi). 
\end{equation}
(b) If the components of $\mathbf{E}_0$ have different phases, you get elliptical polarization.